# PS Vita Help, Trying to charge

Tags: technical-issues, ps-vita

I've had my PS Vita for about 2 years now, and I haven't played on it in a while. I wanted to play on it again, so I charged it for about 2 hours, but the orange light was still blinking.

Is there anyway to fix this?

I love the console and I would do anything to get it back.
I DO use an off-brand charger (my original one stopped charging for some reason), but I have used it before and it worked well!

Comment: Have you tried changing cables? Have you tried charging it using the USB-port of another device (e.g. your laptop), or, if this is what you did, using an AC adapter?